# How to include static data files into Archlinux AUR package?

Tags: archlinux, pkgbuild, pacman-package-manager

I have a small script that uses some static text files as data source. I want to make Archlinux AUR package for this script. I plan to install the script into `/usr/bin/` and static text files somewhere locally `~/.data_files`

I have several static files: data1.txt, data2.txt, data3.txt. Basically, I need the package manager to install the script into `/usr/bin/`, create `~/.data_files` directory and copy the static files there.

How should I configure my PKGBUILD in such case?

Here is my current version:

```
# Maintainer: john doe
pkgname=myscript
pkgver=1.0
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="test script"
arch=(any)
url="https://github.com/me/myscript"
license=('MIT')
depends=('file')
source=('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myscript/master/myscript')
md5sums=('1fa410f1647700a6da3ab0ebyc52465d')

package() {
  install -D -m 755 myscript ${pkgdir}/usr/bin/myscript
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me quote one of the most active moderator of Archlinux Forum when he said [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1562656#p1562656) :

> Do not touch the users home directory in a PKGBUILD, especially do not delete things because **[weird bugs](https://github.com/valvesoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3671)** can do **[bad things](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1202858)**.

Now as a maintainer in AUR, I would suggest to add your statics files in the folder `/usr/share/${pkgname}/` as it's also suggested in [Arch Packaging Standards](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_packaging_standards)

Here's my suggestion *(open for editions, suggestions, advices...)*:

```
# Maintainer: john doe <john at doe dot com>
pkgname=myscript
pkgver=1.0
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="test script"
arch=(any)
url="https://github.com/me/myscript"
license=('MIT')
depends=('file')
source=('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myscript/master/myscript'
      'data1.txt'
      'data2.txt'
      'data3.txt')
sha256sums=('77eff738ea7fdeee5f5707cafdf34f74e3bf8df3b8b656a08a8740a45a7e22c45a7e60c31b13c71f5ee04aff9c82ac43abb39c37b2ea6b02a6454e262f336f73'
       'sha256Ofdata1.txt'
       'sha256Ofdata2.txt'
       'sha256Ofdata3.txt')

package() {
  install -Dm755 myscript "${pkgdir}/usr/share/${pkgname}/myscript"
  install -Dm644 data1.txt "${pkgdir}/usr/share/${pkgname}/data1.txt"
  install -Dm644 data2.txt "${pkgdir}/usr/share/${pkgname}/data2.txt"
  install -Dm644 data3.txt "${pkgdir}/usr/share/${pkgname}/data3.txt"
}
```

Because of **md5** known vulnerabilities, I used **sha256** but you can choose to use other sha* for integrity check.